# Lingua::TreeTagger tagging only first word in Parts Of Speech tagging

Tags: perl, nlp, pos-tagger

I'm using [Lingua::TreeTagger](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-TreeTagger/lib/Lingua/TreeTagger.pm) for POS tagging, but its tagging just first word of string.

```
my $tagger = Lingua::TreeTagger->new(
    'language' => 'english',
    'options'  => [ qw( -token -lemma -no-unknown ) ],
);
$text_to_tag = 'I another yet sample text I.';
my $tagged_text = $tagger->tag_text( \$text_to_tag );
print Dumper $tagged_text;
```

Output of the above dumper is as below:

```
'sequence' => [
                                 bless( {
                                          'is_SGML_tag' => 0,
                                          'original' => 'I',
                                          'tag' => 'PP',
                                          'lemma' => 'I'
                                        }, 'Lingua::TreeTagger::Token' )
                               ],
```

Please note that only `I` is tagged here, but I want to tag whole sentence. In my actual code, I want to tag contents of a file. **How can I tag all words of the sentence?** Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This tags all tokens without any changes on my system, except that my tree-tagger installation had only `lib/english-utf8.par` parameter file so i had to add `use_utf8 => 1` to arguments of `new()`.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but maybe your _english_ parameter file is incomplete. The `-no-unknown` seems to mean _Print the token rather than <unknown> for unknown lemmas_ according to http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/team/~panchenko/def/treetagger/README.txt, but it still looks like it only found `I` because it doesn't know the other words.

Comment: I have changed the order of words in sentence, still it prints about the first one. It means, it knows about the all words, but not scrolling to next. I think I am missing something very basic.
Thanks for your comments :)